# How to join results from one table into pairs

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have a table

pairs

```
    nr_id | Name | Surname | roomate_id
      1   | Tom  | Hopkins |    4
      2   | Mike | Rubens  | 
      3   | Dylan| Obama   |    5
      4   | Jason| Lin     |    1
      5   | Peter| Huang   |    5
    ....  | .... | ....    | ....
```

Is it possible to join this table with sql query to get a such result?

```
    name  | Surname | rommate name|roomate surname
    Tom   | Hopkins | Jason       | Lin
    Jason | Lin     | Tom         | Hopkins
    Dylan | Obama   | Peter       | Huang
    Mike  | Rubens  |             |   
    ....  | ....    |  ...        | ....
```

I would like to group results as 2 persons pairs like above. There are some people without pair

Comment: What does it mean for someone to be their own roommate?  What do you want to do if three people are sharing living quarters?  How do you even represent that in the table?

Comment: It is a very easy situation ;) I need only 2 persons in one room.

Comment: The roomate_id value for the ID 5 is a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join for that. The query would be like :

```
SELECT p1.name,p1.surname,p2.name as roomate_name,p2.surname as roomate_surname
FROM pairs p1
LEFT JOIN pairs p2 on p1.nr_id=p2.roomate_id
WHERE p1.nr_id <> p1.roommate_id
```

Comment: You should add the condition `p1.nr_id <> p1.roommate_id`.

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any chance to group it that persons in pairs would be displayed next to each other?

Comment: do you mean displayed in neighboring rows ?

Comment: yes :) that pairs would be displayed firstly and then people without roomate

Comment: try adding ORDER BY p1.nr_id,p1.roomate_id,this will just leave the people without roomate at the end

Answer (score 0):

This is basic SQL... you just need to join the table with itself like this:

```
SELECT
   p.name,
   p.surname,
   r.name AS roomate_name,
   r.surname AS roomate_surname
FROM pairs p
LEFT JOIN pairs r ON r.nr_id=p.roomate_id
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting the same couple twice you can add a condition

```
SELECT p.name,
       p.surname,
       r.name AS roomate_name,
       r.surname AS roomate_surname
FROM   pairs p
       LEFT JOIN pairs r ON r.nr_id=p.roomate_id
WHERE  p.nr_id > r.nr_id
```